# Urlrewritingnet 301 redirect strange behavior

Tags: php, umbraco, urlrewriting.net

I migrated a site form a php system to Umbraco.
I would like to redirect all the old urls (es: index.php? ...) to the current site root, so I wrote a rule:

```
<urlrewritingnet xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
    <rewrites>        
        <add name="301RedirectDirUrlsOldSite" virtualUrl="^http\://www.mysite.it/index.php(.*)" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="http://www.mysite.it/" redirect="Domain" redirectMode="Permanent" ignoreCase="true" />
    </rewrites>
</urlrewritingnet>
```

The rule works fine but the redirect incluse also the querystring parameters. For example is I fire **www.mysite.it/index.php?p=10&url=test** I've been redirect to the same url (without 404) but not to **www.mysite.it** only as I expect. Is there anything to change over my rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On php rewrites within Umbraco I use the following which should work for you:

```
<add name="phpRewrites" virtualUrl="^~/(.*)\.php(.*)" rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite" redirect="Application" redirectMode="Permanent" destinationUrl="~/" ignoreCase="true" />
```

The difference in the virtualUrl & destinationUrl may seem trivial - but give it a go.